# How to add zooming to d3.js scatter plot with time axis?

Tags: d3.js

I want to add a zoom interaction to my d3.js scatter plot, where x axis is timestamp, y axis is value,The x axis is by month and day now. The zoom function I want is when  I zoom in, hour, minute, second data will be shown in the scatter plot, and when I zoom out ,year data will be shown.
I followed this example https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_zoom.html and the code is as below, but it is not working,please help me to find out the problem.

Below is the code I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- what title to put?? a standard one or one depends on user requirement? -->
    <title>D3: Time axis, prettier</title>

    <!-- Load d3.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* No style rules here yet */   
      .axis path,
      .axis line{
        stroke: black;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }

      .axis text{
        font-family: Optima, Futura, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 8px;
        fill: black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      //Create a function plot, pass all the parameters of size
      //Create more than one SVGs

      //Width and height
      var w = 500;
      var h = 300;
      var padding = 60;
      
      var dataset, xScale, yScale, xAxis, yAxis;  //Empty, for now

      dataset = {"2022-12-30 07:00:42": [16777216.0, 16777216.0], "2022-12-30 04:58:28": [10977.28, 184483.84], "2022-12-29 05:27:05": [422004.0, 489.0], "2022-12-30 12:23:38": [0.0, 0.0], "2022-12-30 07:29:13": [0.0, 2147483647.0], "2022-12-27 14:04:55": [1638.4, 2686.976], "2022-12-30 12:49:34": [4030.464, 2359.296], "2022-12-30 14:22:16": [0.0], "2022-12-30 14:22:34": [0.0], "2022-12-30 05:17:38": [0.197803, 5898.24], "2022-12-30 13:50:11": [62914560.0, 62914560.0], "2023-01-25 11:37:05": [0.0, 610.0], "2022-11-07 14:07:54": [436142.08, 5701.632]}

      //For converting strings to Dates
      var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

      //For converting Dates to strings
      var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%b %e");

      //Function for converting dataset from strings to Dates and numbers
      var formattedData = Object.entries(dataset).map(([key, value]) => {
          return {
              date: parseTime(key),
              values: value
          };
      });


      //Discover start and end dates in dataset
      var startDate = d3.min(formattedData, function(d) { return d.date; });
      var endDate = d3.max(formattedData, function(d) { return d.date; });

      //Create scale functions
      xScale = d3.scaleTime()
               .domain([
                d3.timeDay.offset(startDate, -1),  //startDate minus one day, for padding
                d3.timeDay.offset(endDate, 1)   //endDate plus one day, for padding
              ])
               .range([padding, w - padding]);

      yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([
                d3.min(formattedData, function(d) { return d3.min(d.values);}),  
                d3.max(formattedData, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values);})
              ])
               .range([h - padding, padding]);

      //Define X axis
      xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(xScale)
                .ticks(9)
                .tickFormat(formatTime);

      //Define Y axis
      yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                .scale(yScale)
                .ticks(10);

 
          
      //Create SVG element
      var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

 
  
        
      //Create X axis
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
      
      //Create Y axis
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);
      
      // Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
      var clip = svg.append("defs").append("SVG:clipPath")
          .attr("id", "clip")
          .append("SVG:rect")
          .attr("width", w )
          .attr("height", h )
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", 0);
      // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
      var scatter = svg.append('g')
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

        //Generate circles last, so they appear in front
      scatter.selectAll("circle")
         .data(formattedData)
         .join("g")
         .selectAll("circle").data(d => d.values.map(values => ({ date: d.date, values })))
       
         .join("circle")
         .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xScale(d.date);
         })
         .attr("cy", function(d) {
          // what to do with more than one data on the same date??
            return yScale(d.values);
         })
         .attr("r", 2)
         .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
         ;


          // Set the zoom and Pan features: how much you can zoom, on which part, and what to do when there is a zoom
      var zoom = d3.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([.5, 20])  // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
          .extent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
          .on("zoom", updateChart);

      // This add an invisible rect on top of the chart area. This rect can recover pointer events: necessary to understand when the user zoom
      svg.append("rect")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h)
          .style("fill", "none")
          .style("pointer-events", "all")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
          .call(zoom);
      // now the user can zoom and it will trigger the function called updateChart

      // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available
      function updateChart({transform}) {

        // recover the new scale
        var newX = transform.rescaleX(xScale);
      
        var newY = transform.rescaleY(yScale);


        // update axes with these new boundaries
        xAxis.scale(newX);
         
        yAxis.scale(newY);
           

        // update circle position
        scatter
          .selectAll("circle")
          .attr('cx', function(d) {return newX(d.Sepal_Length)})
          .attr('cy', function(d) {return newY(d.Petal_Length)});
      }


 
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is old version of d3.js